# explode comma from textbox

Tags: php, explode

Can any one help me to explode last comma?

```
column name = used_receipt
```

values comes  in column like below...

```
301,302,303,
```

Now the problem is when I try to get min and max value from this textbox and click save, the for loop goes into an infinite loop because of last comma.

```
if(isset($_POST['save'])){
    $used_receipt = $_POST['used_receipt']; 
    $arr = array_filter(explode(",", $used_receipt));

    $min = min($arr);
    $max = max($arr);
    for ($i = $min; $i <= $max; $i++){
        $insertrow = $database->insertRow("INSERT INTO book_return (used_receipt) VALUES (:used_receipt)", 
                array(':used_receipt'=>$i));                
    }
}
```

Comment: How is this question related to PDO?

Comment: `rtrim ($string, ',')`

Comment: Well, take a look what values are really contained in `$min` and `$max`, I'd say. or are we meant to _guess_? You do not do any form f error checking when looking for the min and max values. No wonder you ask questions when things don't work as expected.

Comment: how to implemet rtrim ($string, ',') this in $arr = explode(", ", $used_receipt);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rtrim($used_receipt, ',');
```

This will trim out suffixing comma's.

Comment: but plz tell how to implement this   rtrim ($string, ',') this in $arr = explode(", ", $used_receipt);

Comment: `$arr = explode(",", rtrim($used_receipt, ','));`

Comment: values comes in my textbox like 700, 701,

Comment: before exploding maybe this? `$used_receipt = rtrim($used_receipt, ',');`

Comment: *This will trim out prefixing and suffixing* No it only will trim commas at the end not at the start!

Comment: rtrim — Strip whitespace (or other characters) from the end of a string. - from php.net... no idea why i thought otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

You made two mistakes:

1. You have a space in your explode statement

2. You don't remove empty values from your array

So to get rid of these mistakes you can do this:

```
$arr = array_filter(explode(",", $used_receipt));
     //^^^^^^^^^^^^          ^ See only a comma without a space
     //| To remove empty values from your array
```

Comment: @sunilsatpute It should, because the last comma just gives you a empty array element which then get's removed from `array_filter()`, what is the output of `var_dump($used_receipt);` to make sure you get `301,302,303,` as input

Comment: @sunilsatpute Please update your question with your **full** and **real** code

Comment: @sunilsatpute Also please add what the **exact** output of  `var_dump($used_receipt);` is

Comment: @s Just add a line after this: `$used_receipt = $_POST['used_receipt']; ` So that your code looks like this: `$used_receipt = $_POST['used_receipt'];  var_dump($used_receipt);` and the post the output here

Comment: i am inserting value like 301,302,303,  but due to last comma this is not inserting in tables.. and if i remove this than works properly..

Comment: yes bcoz i need to insert row from min to max and my min and max are used_recipt...

Comment: @sunilsatpute You still didn't tell my what the output of `var_dump($used_receipt);` is! This is very important

Comment: @sunilsatpute this code that @Rizier123 gave you will work if your `$used_receipt` is a string. Only with a `var_dump()` to this variable will help us to help you!

Comment: but sir i already tell you whein i put your code this insert null values in used_receipt column....plz update code accordingly....i also try  $arr = explode(",", rtrim($used_receipt, ','));  but this is also not work in my case...plz suggest genuine solution...

Comment: @sunilsatpute For the 5 time! Tell us the output of `var_dump($used_receipt);` !! This is very very important, whats actually in this variable!

Comment: @sunilsatpute Try this: `array_filter(explode(",", str_replace(" ", "", $used_receipt)));`

Comment: sir exactly what output you needed ...i tell you input in used_receipt column like 700, 701, .....and when i click save this will insert nothing in used_receipt column...only this insert other input in table..but not this values...

Comment: @sunilsatpute 1. Why can't you just tell us what the output of `var_dump($used_receipt);` is? 2. Have you tried this: `array_filter(explode(",", str_replace(" ", "", $used_receipt)));` ?